# The method RegisterCustomer isn't defined for the class Dashboard when routing to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have Dashboard screen in lib directory. The register_customer.dart file is under customers subdirectory in lib folder. I have imported **register_customer.dart** in dashboard screen. However the RegisterCustomer class in **register_customer.dart** is not resolving. Here is my code:

**lib/dashboard.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './customers/register_customer.dart';

class MyDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
            elevation: 0,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: btnTextColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //navigate to the previous page
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            //navabar title text text
            title: Text('Dashboard'),
           
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                //color: Colors.amber[600],
                width: 200.0,
                height: 250.0,
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'Register Customer',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffE06C19)),
                        ),
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.user,
                          color: Colors.amber,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
         **//this is where the error is being raised**
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => RegisterCustomer()));
                      },
                    ),
                                       
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ))),
    );
  }
}
lib/customers/register_customer.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class RegisterCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterCustomerState createState() => _RegisterCustomerState();
}

String _first_name;
String _last_name;

class _RegisterCustomerState extends State<RegisterCustomer> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.purple[800],
          accentColor: Colors.amber,
          accentColorBrightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Register Customer',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[                       
               
                       SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Color(0xff980CF0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  splashColor: Colors.grey,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                      return;
                    }
                    //submit data to the server
                   
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am experiencing same issue with other routes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the import path is incorrect:

```dart
import 'package:projectname/customer/register_customer.dart
```

if the file is in `lib/customer/register_customer.dart`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though have tried importing the file as suggested but ending up with the same error. I simply don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: @wafutech I hope you replaced "projactname" with the actual projectname.
For further help I would need a screenshot of the filestructure of the project